# I want to install 12.04 instead of 13.10, what should I do?

Tags: 12.04, installation, 13.10, uninstall, downgrade

I run Ubuntu 13.10 but I think it doesn't work properly. I’m facing problems, being unable to listen to the music and watch movies, I either can't use Internet. Machine looks connected, but when browser do not load any web page. 
Because of mentioned problems I believe think it is better to install Ubuntu 12.04.3 and I have downloaded it already. How can I uninstall 13.10 and install 12.04 .

Is there any one who can help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First backup all your datas to a partition other than ubuntu 13.10 partition.
- Create a bootable ubuntu 12.04 live usb through unetbootin software.
- Boot from the live usb and then run the ubuntu installer.During the installation process,select *something else* option which make you to choose on which partition you have to install ubuntu 12.04.
- Select the partition where ubuntu 13.10 is installed,rightclick on it and then format it to *ext4* filesystem.
- Choose the same formatted partition to install ubuntu 12.04.Then install ubuntu on it.